# How to render 2 fields at a time from Redux fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am loading data from api at a time 5 records , I want to render 2 records on first time, after clicking load more another 2 records have come.
Redux fields array

```
<FieldArray name="facilityData"
                        component={this.getFacilities}
                    />
```

Returning function it includes map function which is running and rendering redux fields

```
getFacilities = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => {

return fields.map((facility, index) => {
return <div>{index}</div>
})
}
```

I have implemented fields.slice() but this function is not working in Redux forms fields

I have tried

> ```
> getFacilities = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => {
>
>         const setss = [...Array(fields)];
>         console.log(setss);
>     }
> ```

it s returning : [image]

I want to load 2 records at a time, how can I add break using fields.map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index in the map function to control how many of the fields should display. Returning `null` will render nothing. You need to handle increasing the `fieldsToShow` variable yourself though.

```js
const fieldsToShow = 2; // could be pulled from state


getFacilities = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => {
  return fields.map((facility, index) => {
    return index < Math.min(fieldsToShow, fields.length) ? <div>{/* Render the field */}</div> : null
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to me, but from this, I can only load 2 items, I want to append other items by clicking load more button. How can I write that one? can you please help me . I really appreciate that

Comment: In fields. map function there are 5 objects coming from API, I want to load 2 at a time then click load more append 2 more data into it, I don't know how to break map function without using slice method